# Does aria-label prevent the inner content being read out by assistive devices?

Tags: html, wai-aria

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute) say you should use `aria-label` like this:

```
<button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

I don't have access to a screenreader, but I've seen comments on Stack Overflow suggesting that an `aria-label` does not *replace* the inner content, it only *prefixes* it. So in the above case it would read out "Close X", which is obviously not ideal.

Is this true? If so, what's the solution? I'm guessing it would make sense to wrap the inner content with an `[aria-hidden=true]` element, like this:

```
<button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
```

...but I'm cautious because I can't test it on a real screenreader.

Comment: Why can't you test on a screenreader? [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/) is a free screenreader. I've tested it in IE, Chrome, and FF on Windows and it works great for testing your accessibility work. If you haven't tested your site/app using an actual screenreader, you're going to be in for some surprises.

Comment: Like most web developers (in Europe/US at least), I use macOS to develop. It sucks that there is no good screenreader available for macOS. It's not a question of just hopping over to a Windows machine to check it works on a screenreader; web dev just doesn't work like that. The quality standard of accessibility is never going to get higher while no serious screenreader software is available for the OS that web developers actually use.

Comment: Web developers might not use it, but in the visually impaired community the 'go-to' resource for mac is VoiceOver on a Safari browser. In my opinion and in my practice, this is what we use for (one phase of) our accessibility testing, even if as a web developer I work with Chrome and/or Firefox.

Answer (score 10):

In most situations, the aria-label will be read out *instead of* the link's text.

This is actually a standard test scenario, and has extensive test results on powermapper: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/a-aria-label/

On the test results page, you can also hear the screen reader output.

Answer (score 6):

**FINAL EDIT**

Instead of relying on blog posts or misinterpreting specs, I think it's better to actually test things rather than come to a conclusion and trying to remember everything about ARIA.

You can test what the **accessible name** of an element is, for e.g. if you use Google Chrome (hopefully other browsers include accessibility testing tools):

1. Open dev tools (e.g. <kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows).
2. Select the element (with the pointer or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +
   <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>)
3. Click the **Accessibility** tab (here you can view the Accessibility
   tree, ARIA attributes and Computed properties.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But [these official guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html) recommend using `aria-label` on a `[role=tablist]` element to explain the *purpose* of the set of tabs. Such labelling would obviously be supplementary information; the intention is surely not to *override* the text nodes within (i.e. the individual tab titles), as that would make the tabs unusable in screenreaders. This makes me doubt your conclusion that `aria-label` overrides inner text nodes.

Comment: All UI components are expected to behave differently, I don't understand why you are making this about tabs all of a sudden. Also, what the aria-label in that context does, is it gives the [role="tablist"] element an accessible name. It does not override the text-node of the buttons.

Comment: Here's a practical guide for developers on how to add accessibility to html: [https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/)

Comment: I'm not making it about tabs all of a sudden. The question is about `aria-label` generally – does it replace or supplement inner content? I used `button` as an example because it's a simple case, but I'm interested in anywhere the attribute can be used.

Comment: Your Edit#2 suggests aria-label overrides _only_ text nodes that are direct children of the aria-labelled element. What about something like `<button>Go to our <span class="big">homepage</span></button>`? I can't believe it would treat the span as semantically separate from the direct text node.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer, using the Windows Narrator:

- When the Narrator is reading the text and finds a button in the middle of it, `aria-label` is in fact prefixing the content, like this:
  *[content before button] [`aria-label` value] [text inside the button tag] [content after button]*.
- When the user focuses (or clicks) the button, the narrator only says the `aria-label` value, and not the content inside the button, like this:
  *[`aria-label` value]* "button".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while fine-tuning an app to better support the JAWS screen reader.

I hope to help anyone else who comes across this question by pointing out that macOS has a perfectly functional screen reader built in called VoiceOver (VO) which can be activated with cmd+F5.

Alternatively, macOS users can install Windows (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) through free software like VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/), which is perfectly adequate for testing with the likes of NVDA and even JAWS if you or your organisation are willing to pay for the licence fee.

The moral of my answer is that you CAN just hop over to a Windows machine to check it works not just on a screenreader, but also the myriad Windows web browsers that I'm sure a varying percent of your visitors use - web dev DOES work like that.

**UPDATE:** while I understand the down votes due to my answer not actually answering callum's question, I feel comments such as on "Mar 22 at 11:41" have a negative impact on the community and need addressing. If I have opened just one developer's mindset to cross-OS and accessibility testing it was worth it.